# find out the number of different blood types in a sample population by antigen counts

Tags: combinatorics

Assume an antigen count has recently been compiled by a hospital. The scientist only counted the antigens spotted but forgot to label the blood types of all her patients. Here's the data she has left:

25 individuals have A antigens, 27 have B antigens, 30 have Rh antigens, 16 have A and Rh antigens, 17 have A and B antigens, 22 have B and Rh antigens, 12 have no antigens and 15 have A, B and Rh antigens.

How many individuals have each of the eight blood types? How would you do this kind of problem when having A antigens means a broader set of many smaller subsets like part of having A and B antigens, A and Rh antigens, etc...?

Comment: It would help the non-biology people if you listed specifically which blood types have which antigens

Comment: @ThomasGrubb I'm guessing that the blood types correspond to the subsets of $\{A,B,Rh\}$.

Comment: @KevinLong  I think so too. The empty set is what would be called O-negative. That seems to have 12 instances.

Comment: @KevinLong  The eight blood types are $A^+, A^-, B^+, B^-, AB^+, AB^-, O^+, O^-$, where $O$ means the absence of the $A$ and $B$ antigens, $AB$ means both are present, $^+$ means the $Rh$ factor is present, and $^-$ means it is absent.

Comment: Now that we understand what the red stuff that flows through our bodies is, I'd recommend that you draw a Venn diagram. You'll have three circles, one representing each antigen with all possible intersections. Then you can associate each of these numbers with some regions of the diagram (including the outside). From there, you can make some deductions based on how these blood types relate. As an example, if 22 people have $B$ and $Rh$ antigens, and $15$ have all three, then there must be $7$ with $B$ and $Rh$ but not $A$. Try making deductions like those to fill in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Blood types:

$AB^+$: has $A$, $B$, and $Rh$ antigens
$AB^-$: has $A$ and $B$ but not $Rh$ antigens
$A^+$: has $A$ and $Rh$ but not $B$ antigens
$A^-$: has $A$ but neither $B$ nor $Rh$ antigens
$B^+$: has $B$ and $Rh$ but not $A$ antigens
$B^-$: has $B$ but neither $A$ nor $Rh$ antigens
$O^+$: has $Rh$ but neither $A$ nor $B$ antigens
$O^-$: has neither $A$ nor $B$ nor $Rh$ antigens

Consider the Venn diagram below.

[image: Venn_diagram_for_blood_types]

Since there are $12$ individuals with no antigens, we place a $12$ in the region outside the three circles that represent $A \cup B \cup C$.  These individuals are $O^-$.

For the remaining individuals, we will work from the inside out.

Since there are $15$ individuals with $A$, $B$, and $Rh$ antigens, $|A \cap B \cap Rh| = 15$.  These individuals are $AB^+$.

[image: blood_type_Venn_diagram_with_initial_steps]

We know there are $16$ individuals with $A$ and $Rh$ antigens, of whom $15$ have $A$, $B$, and $Rh$ antigens.  Hence, there is $16 - 15 = 1$ individual who has $A$ and $Rh$ but not $B$ antigens.  This individual has blood type $A^+$.

We know there are $22$ individuals with $B$ and $Rh$ antigens, of whom $15$ have $A$, $B$, and $Rh$ antigens.  Hence, there are $22 - 15 = 7$ individuals who have $B$ and $Rh$ but not $A$ antigens.  These individuals have blood type $B^+$.

We know there are $17$ individuals with $A$ and $B$ antigens, of whom $15$ have $A$, $B$, and $Rh$ antigens.  Hence, there are $17 - 15 = 2$ individuals who have $A$ and $B$ but not $Rh$ antigens.  These individuals have blood type $AB^-$.

[image: blood_type_Venn_diagram_with_completed_intersections]

We know that we have a total of $30$ individuals with $Rh$ antigens, of whom $15$ also have both $A$ and $B$ antigens, $1$ also has $A$ but not $B$ antigens, and $7$ also have $B$ but not $A$ antigens.  Hence, the number who have only $Rh$ antigens is $30 - (15 + 1 + 7) = 30 - 23 = 7$.  These individuals have blood type $O^+$.

[image: almost_complete_blood_type_Venn_diagram]

I will leave it to you to calculate the number of $A^-$ and $B^-$ individuals.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include Venn diagrams, which should make it easier to understand.